# Setting `colorcolumn` to the value of `textwidth` has no effect?

Tags: colorcolumn, textwidth

I want to mark the `textwidth`<sup>th</sup> column using `colorcolumn` and have used
the following (since I have slightly different `textwidth`s for different files)

```
au FileType py set textwidth=80 (say line 98)
au FileType c set textwidth=79 (say line 99)
let &colorcolumn=&textwidth (say line 100)
```

As you can see I have made sure that `textwidth` has been defined before `colorcolumn` is being set. I have also checked the output of the following commands
(inside a `.c` file)

```
:verbose set textwidth?
textwidth=79
    Last set from my_vimrc line 99
:verbose set colorcolumn?
colorcolumn=0
    Last set from my_vimrc line 100
```

As you can see the value is `0` even though no other file is changing the value. Any reason why this might be happening ?

**On a related note**, vim is not breaking lines at 79 characters within `.c` file even though `textwidth` is set to `79`. Could this also be a part of the problem ??

Comment: `formatoptions=ql`

Comment: Without `t` (or `c` for comments only) the auto-wrapping is disabled. (Just to address your "on a related note" part.) Most people want this for coding, I think.

Comment: should I add a `fo+=t` then on its own ? or should I write it as an autocommand for C files only ?

Comment: Well, like I just added in my edit to my comment, it's off deliberately since auto-wrapping is kinda bad for coding. But if you want it on then it depends on if you want it just for C in which case autocommand (or, maybe better, adding an "after" file) is fine. You'll have to see if it's on/off for other file types to your liking.

Comment: Sure. Regarding colorcoumn...surely due to timings of autocommands (they are fired after initial vimrc processing). Easy verification/workaround: set colorcolumn in the autocommands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are expected to do: `set cc=+0`

Why your stuff doesn't work: because ordinary `:set` is executed once, while `:autocmd FileType` is executed upon each `FileType` event.

Note: your `autocmd` has all possible "novice bugs" in it. Before doing any stuff with auto-commands you're strongly advised to learn the docs. In particular, always use `augroup`; prefer `after-directory` over manual `autocmd` etc.

Comment: thanks. I had removed the `augroup`s for the sake of brevity.